# PostgreSQL: generate all possible strings of arbitrary length from a set of characters

Tags: postgresql, recursion, plpgsql

I'm trying to generate all possible strings of length `x` using a fixed set of characters in PostgreSQL. For the simple case of `x = 2` I can use the query below, but I cannot figure out how to do it for an arbitrary length (I'm assuming this will involve recursion):

```
with characters (c) as (
  select unnest(array['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
) 
select concat(c1.c, c2.c)
from characters c1
cross join characters c2
```

This generates `aa`, `ab`, `ac`, `ad`, `ba`, `bb`, `bc`, `bd`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using recursive CTE:

```
with recursive characters (c) as (
  select unnest(array['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
), param(val) AS (
   VALUES (4)   -- here goes param value
), cte AS (
  select concat(c1.c, c2.c) AS c, 2 AS l
  from characters c1
  cross join characters c2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CONCAT(c1.c, c2.c), l + 1
  FROM cte c1
  CROSS JOIN characters c2
  WHERE l <= (SELECT val FROM param)
)
SELECT c
FROM cte
WHERE l = (SELECT val FROM param)
ORDER BY c;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ee6ff5ac1c8b0c0b15b55a513d8cb301)**